# Is there any recommended package for converting A4 size PDF page into A3 size page?

Tags: pdfpages, paper-size, printing, booklet

Currently I'm able to generate required output file using `pdflatex` in A4 page size. To reduce printing cost, I'd like to convert this A4 size PDF into A3 page as mentioned in the diagram below. Is there any package which can help to generate an A3 page PDF?

[Note: There can be A4 size PDF file with 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 pages]

[image]

Kindly suggest.

Comment: How about a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Normally, a call to `pdfnup --paper a3paper --landscape foo.pdf` should yield such a file

Comment: Does [my answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154810/) help at all? If you use `signature=4` then you will get the first 4 pages on the first sheet, the next 4 on the next sheet etc. and won't need to reorder the pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do with the package `pdfpages`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={4,1,2,3},nup=2x2]{test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Or even with the `graphicx` package if you want a custom layout:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[landscape,a3paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0cm,bmargin=0cm,lmargin=0cm,rmargin=0cm}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\centering
\includegraphics[page=4,width=.5\paperwidth,height=.49\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{test.pdf}
\includegraphics[page=2,width=.5\paperwidth,height=.49\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{test.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[page=1,width=.5\paperwidth,height=.49\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{test.pdf}
\includegraphics[page=3,width=.5\paperwidth,height=.49\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The  `test.tex` file used for obtain `test.pdf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{A4-1} \lipsum[1-8]\newpage
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{A4-2} \lipsum[1-8]\newpage
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{A4-3} \lipsum[1-8]\newpage
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{A4-4} \lipsum[1-8]\newpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with the `pdfpages`  package. I'll give a real example of mine used to make an A5 booklet on A4 paper, and explain the details:

I first compiled my main document, say `mymaindoc.tex` with this first line:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt, twoside]{book}
```

Then I created another document `mybooklet.tex`, in A4 landscape format,  with this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, twoside]{book}%

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages = {1,{},2-23},signature=28,landscape]{mymaindoc.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The **pages** key enumerates the first page (title page), an empty page so that the body begins on an odd page, and every page of mymaindoc.pdf from the second one. That makes a total of 25 pages.

The **signature** key is the smallest multiple of 4 that is ≥ 25.

Answer (score 1):

If your workflow already involves non-TeX programs, you may consider the `makebook` program:

https://github.com/dgoodmaniii/makebook

You'll have to download and use a separate program; but you won't have to create and compile a separate TeX file.  Away from my computer right now; but since your target page size is just twice your source page size, something like the following should do it:

```
makebook -i source.pdf -o target.pdf -t folio
```

`makebook` uses `pdfpages` internally (which is a fantastic package), but automates the drudgery of using it.  It does require a `bash` shell, though.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of `makebook`, and am therefore biased about its usefulness.