# including three-page pdf in the latex

Tags: tables, pdfpages

This has been asked before but none of them solve my problem.
I have a three-page pdf which includes a Table, so I would like to have it captioned Table. To include it in my thesis I have tried the followings:

1. With the following what I get is only first page of the pdf, I have tried pages=[3] and pages=[1,2,3], pages={-} and pages={1-}. did not work

```
\begin{table}[h]
 \centering
 \caption{caption.}
 \label{tbl:table}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,pages={1-}]{fig/table.pdf}
\end{table}
```

2. The following put the tables on tope of the text! so it overlaps with the the page. I have tried \newpage. did not work.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
    \caption{caption.}
\includepdf[pages={-},  width=\textwidth, 
  height=\textheight, pagecommand={\label{tbl:table}}, 
]{fig/table.pdf}
\end{table}
```

3. the one that works fine is the following. however I cannot place properly the caption. It appears on the first row of the table.

```
\includepdf[pages={1-},  width=\textwidth, 
  height=\textheight, pagecommand={\label{table} ,\captionof{s}{caption}}, 
]{fig/table.pdf}
```

Please help if you know how to make it right.
thanks in advanced.

Comment: A float like table cannot contain material that spans multiple pages. Includegraphics can only include one page at a time. Includepdf creates full pages so too large for a float. Perhaps you should give more detail as to what your data is, then perhaps there are better alternatives

Comment: the pdf contains a table that is three pages long.

Comment: Moreover, with `\includegraphics` is `page`  (singular) and obviously, just one number (e.g. `page=1`) and of course repeat the command for the other pages. With `\includepdf` is not `pages=[1,2,3]` but  `pages={1,2,3}` and  `{-}`  and `{1-}` should work too, but without a MWE like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/206747/11604) is impossible to assure what is failing in your case.

Comment: Then you cannot use a float like table. Why do you have the table as a pdf in the first place? Latex is fully capable of typesetting multipage tables using, say, longtable

Comment: yes includepdf works, just that I cannot position the caption right. do you have any idea? It is easier for me to draw the table with word!

Comment: As said, a float in not the place for a multipage PDF.

Comment: ok. so what would you do that?

Comment: Just remove the `\begin{table}`  and `\end{table}` lines. BTW, include a  Word table in a PDF in LaTeX is like go to a five stars restaurant to ask a burger `:(`

Comment: then it is going the be third option in the question text, which i have trouble with the caption.

Comment: See the caption package a f the `\captionof` command, but  as said, this is going to look bad