# Trying to print to 11x17 as a book, but scale pages with booklet, margin problems

Tags: margins, scaling, books, booklet

I'm trying to print a book to be bound in signatures for a finished size of 6x9 inches.  My printer duplexes but only prints 11x17.  I used the booklet package and set source to 6x9, but when the pages print the inside margin is about 1.5".  My bookbinder says he needs them to be 3/4", but if I adjust them with setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in} and the same for oddsidemargin they remain the same but both pages print with the margins on the same side - both pages are laid out the same.
  I've only been using LaTex for about three days, so apologies if this is a trivial question - I'm trying to get this book printed before Christmas.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I used to use `booklet` but I gave up. The easiest thing is to set the pages how you want them (use e.g. `geometry` rather than setting things manually). Then use a second `.tex` file with `pdfpages` to include the pages 2-up. It would be easier to explain with an example but if you search the site, you will find similar examples to copy.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154777/a5-booklet-printing-title-page-and-toc-are-missing/154810#154810. The first method is broken (when I last checked) but the second should work.