# Print two selected pages in one

Tags: positioning, printing

I want to print a book with my printer and, because I will fold them in two, I have to print two pages of the book on one real page.
Because I am printing a book, I also have to print the pages of the book in a different order as the normal one.
How can I do both?
I am in the book class.

Comment: Welcome! Your printer should have an option to print in "Booklet" style. Or is this not available for you?

Comment: Otherwise have a look at the [`pdfpages`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) package

Comment: @Troy Depending on the size of the book, I don't think `booklet` is a good suggestion. `pdfpages`, however, is, as it knows about signatures.

Comment: See my answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154777/a5-booklet-printing-title-page-and-toc-are-missing/154810#154810. Note that you should ignore the first solution and scroll down to the second. The first no longer works. The second, however, works fine. For a book, you will want multiple signatures and will need to decide on their size. (I.e. you won't want just one, as for a booklet.) But otherwise, the problem is the same.

Comment: @cfr I was referring to booklet as a printer option. As in, not LaTeX related. I wonder why that is not an option/ acceptable solution?

Comment: @Troy Because I think that most printer options called `booklet` will create a single signature. That is fine for a booklet, but not good for a book!

Comment: @Troy I may be wrong about what the option does, of course. I've certainly not made an exhaustive study of all printers with the option or, indeed, of even a few of them. But when I've used the option, that's what it has done.